# Show determinant is non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A,B \in M_{2}(\mathbb R)$ . Show that $\det((AB+BA)^4 + (AB-BA)^4)\geq 0$

My attempt: expression becomes $\det(2(M-N)^2+16MN)$ where $M=(AB)^2$ and $N=(BA)^2$.

Not sure how to continue from here.

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Let $d=\det(AB-BA)$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be the two eigenvalues of $AB+BA$. Since $X^2=-\det(X)I_2$ and in turn $X^4=\det(X)^2I_2$ for any traceless $2\times2$ matrix $X$, we get
$$
\det\left[(AB+BA)^4 + (AB-BA)^4\right]
=\det\left[(AB+BA)^4 + d^2I_2\right]
=(\lambda_1^4+d^2)(\lambda_2^4+d^2).
$$
As $AB+BA$ is real, either $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are both real or they are complex conjugates to each other. In either case, the assertion follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that approaching the problem is easier by showing the [Positive Semi-Definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) of M and N. This way you can generalize it to $A,B \in R^{n \times n}$.

Expanding the square of matrix $AB$ and $BA$ according to [this source](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenbau/Math_554/Course_Notes/ch1.5.pdf), $M = (AB)^2 = ABB^TA^T, N = (BA)^2 = BAA^TB^T$ are symmetric. As the result their eigenvalues are real.

Moreover, M and N are PSD (shown at the end of the answer). The determinant of a PSD matrix is greater or equal to zero. Thus, it is enough to show that $2(M - N)^2 + 16MN = 2M^2 + 12MN + 2N^2$ is PSD. And this is trivial since it is a summation and product of symmetric PSD matrices.

M is PSD if $x^TMx \geq 0$ $\forall x \in R^n$ $\implies x^TABB^TA^Tx = \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,(AB)_i\rangle^2 \geq 0$ where $(AB)_i$ is $i$th column of matrix $AB$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. When you say 'eigenvalues of T4T4 and T′4T′4 are non-negative or in other words they are Positive Semi Definite since they are raised by the power of 4', what if the eigenvalues of T and T' are complex? How can you guarantee that their fourth powers will be non-negative?

Comment: But in which condition do they become complex while $A,B \in R^{n \times n}$?

Comment: For example look at the matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$.

Comment: Can you explain how you have got $\det(2(M-N)^2+16MN$?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I've edited it above

Comment: Okay. It can be shown that M and N are symmetric. Which means their eigenvalues are real. And they are square of a real matrix which suggests that they are PSD. $2(M - N) + 16MN = 2M + 2N + 14MN$ is summation of three PSD matrices which is still PSD.

Comment: I'm afraid M and N need not symmetric. e.g. $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix} and B = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66486/discussion-between-mohammad-and-rishi).

Comment: The expansion of $(AB)^2$ is not how I would usually interpret things. I would usually put $(AB)^2=ABAB$ instead.

Comment: Then it doesn't work if $AB \in R^{m \times p}$. (not necessary for this question)